# How auto updated the database without refresh with ajax?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

i'm new here. i just create a code which can read the data from mysql database. 
But when i add in new data inside databse, my php page cant updated own automatic. 
I want the page can updated automaticly withour press f5 button and refresh.
Can anyone help me solve this?

Get any misstake??

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function List(){
    var ajaxRequest;
    var selectedProduct = ""; 
    var product = document.getElementById('product');
    var output ="";         
    var k = 0;  
//  var name = new Array;
//  var model = new Array;
    var unitprice = new Array;
    var queryString = new Array;

    queryString = "&name=" + txtname + "&model=" + txtmodel + ;
            ajaxRequest.open("GET", $productPrice + queryString, true);
            ajaxRequest.send(null); 
    ajaxRequest.open("GET", $productPrice + queryString, true);
    ajaxRequest.send(null); 

        <?php foreach ($productPrices as $price): ?>
            name[k] = "<?php echo $price['Product']['txtname']; ?>";
            model[k] = "<?php echo $price['Product']['txtmodel']; ?>";
            k++;

        <?php endforeach; ?>

        k=0;
        for (var i = 0; i < product.length; i++) { 
                k = product.options[i].value;

            if (product.options[i].selected) {  
                output += '<tr>'+
                                '<td style="border-right: 0px; width:270px; text-align:center" id="ProductProduct'+k+'" name="data[Product][Product]['+k+']">'+name[i]+'</td>'+
                                '<td style="border-right: 0px; width:100px; text-align:left" id="ProductProduct'+k+'" name="data[Product][Product]['+k+']">'+model[i]+'</td>'+
                            '</tr>';    
            }
        } 
        output = '<table style="width:500px; border: 0px;">'+output+'</table>';         
        document.getElementById('productTable').innerHTML = output;
}                   
</script>
```

Comment: a javascriptlibrary might make this job easier

Comment: Yea, although working with what you have where do you call Function List?

Answer (score 1):

You need some kind of repeated AJAX check in your page to see if there is new data in the database.  You can do this using setTimeout or setInterval.

E.g.

```
function CheckData() {
    List();
    setTimeout(CheckData, 10000);
}
```

Comment: @ck: just a comment, I don't know how much data we are talking about and how many users but that gonna load the server *fast*....

Comment: @RageZ - its just a potential solution.  The timeout can be extended, and ideally it should be profiled to make the slowest parts more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

```
setInterval(function() {
    List(); // your function
      // Do something every 2 seconds
}, 2000);
```

this is jquery function this will help you.